# how to create virtual environment for python 2.7

Tags: python

I have python3 installed in my PC. I got a project requirement for which python version is 2.7. Can i create a virtual environment with python 2.7?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/key_projects/#virtualenv

Comment: You can use `anyenv` or `pywin` in windows and `pyenv` in linux

Answer (score 1):

yep.

Virtualenv is in your hands:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html

```
Thinkpad:~$ virtualenv -p <path to installed python 2.x /python-2.x/bin/python> venv



Thinkpad:~$ source venv/bin/activate


(venv) Thinkpad:~$
```